# redirect http to https in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-controller

I have a follow up question about redirecting grails apps from http to https.  another user showed me that, the config file, i can do something like this:

```
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',]
```

right now, this will cause the user to see a page that says:

Unable to connect
      Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8443.

Is this what it should be doing?  if so, how do i have my grails app redirect to https?

thanks!
jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails doesn't run over HTTPS by default.  You'll need to execute [run-app with -https option](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html).

Comment: thanks.  i already have HTTPS set up.  I just want to make sure that if a user tries to go to http they get redirected to https.  right now, using the code i posted earlier, it just turns off access to the site if they go to http.  i want to keep that but redirect to https

Comment: So you can manually navigate to https://localhost:8443/ to a non-secure page and it works?

Comment: as it turns out, i think my problem is with AWS and their port config.  I will re post this question.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is usually over port 443 not 8443 - this could be your problem or typo in your question?

Comment: no, i copied it directly from the error page.  it does say 8443

Comment: Sorry - I hoped it might be a quick for you!

Comment: Tomcat's default SSL port is 8443, similar to how its default non-ssl port is 8080, rather than 80.  Most folks are running Apache in front of Tomcat, therefor, different port #'s are required.